# Is there any limit on the number of tables we can create in single database in MySql?

Tags: mysql, database

Somewhere on web I've seen an article saying that there is a restriction on the number of tables we can create in MySQL? or maybe I misunderstood.

I just want to confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/database-count-limit.html

> MySQL has no limit on the number of databases. The underlying file
>   system may have a limit on the number of directories.
>
> MySQL has no limit on the number of tables. The underlying file system
>   may have a limit on the number of files that represent tables.
>   Individual storage engines may impose engine-specific constraints.
>   InnoDB permits up to 4 billion tables.